# Needs to restrict accessing to webadmin (Icewarp merak)

Tags: linux, email, redhat

I want if there is a way or option to restrict accessing to webadmin panel (like i want someone with certian IP can logIN into webadmin and blockings anyone else) .

BTW i'm using version icewarp merak 9.4.2 on RedHAT 5.3

Answer (score 1):

I don't WTF this "icewarp merak" thing is (Google suggests it's a mail server), but it should have the ability to restrict access to a particular URL to a specific IP (or range of IPs).  If it doesn't, you can either get a real web server, or proxy access to the webadmin panel through a real web server.  Given that this thing looks like it's proprietary software, why not ask the vendor for the support you're (presumably) paying for?

Comment: I second the apache / other web server proxy idea